# active directory auth getting invalid attribute description

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Authentication works fine if I just use sAMAccountName.  When i try to filter using

> 'memberOf=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(|(department=861)(department=945)))'

as my ldap property name for login i get

> javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: invalid attribute
>   description;

Ive tried with/without the memberOf= bit.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most servers which use `memberOf` have an attribute definition for the attribute that defines it as having `DN` syntax (`1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12`). If that is the case with your server, that assertion in the filter cannot succeed because the attribute value in the assertion is not a DN.